# ReplaceAll in an expression including large InterpolatingFunction

Tags: replacement, interpolation

I have a large `InterpolatingFunction` that I'm transforming to another basis with a few simple multiplications and additions by (symbolic) constants. The transformation is quick to compute. However, when I later want to replace the symbolic constants with real numbers for plotting purposes, a call to `ReplaceAll` grinds for an exceptionally long time on the expression.

Why? Is there a way to avoid this without replacing in the transformation itself (an alternative I'd like to avoid for procedural reasons).

I would provide code, but I don't know a short snippet that can generate a large interpolating function. Perhaps someone can provide a good example.

Comment: I am afraid that without code, you significantly reduce your chances to get a good answer. Try to simplify your real case to a minimal example exhibiting this behavior.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, I was able to work around it by replacing the variables before transforming the basis. I found the issue unreliable to reproduce, with some lists of replacement rules computing `ReplaceAll` quickly, and others taken a very long time.

Comment: The problem is that until you could provide a reproducible example, we can only guess. One such guess is that this might be related to unpacking of packed arrays. You can switch the monitoring of packing on, by calling `On["Packing"]` (or `Off["Packing"]` to switch this off, and see if the long timings correlate with unpacking messages.

Comment: I think you're right. I'm getting messages like `Developer\`FromPackedArray::punpack1: Unpacking array with dimensions {1010}` for the calls to `ReplaceAll` that take a long time and no such messages for others.

Comment: Then the thing you are observing is similar to what was happening [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700934/why-is-cases-so-slow-here-are-there-any-tricks-to-speed-it-up). Here is the cure: whatever your rules are, say `{a->1, b->2}`, add the following rule in front: ``arr_List?Developer`PackedArrayQ :> arr`` (so for my example, you'd have ``{arr_List?Developer`PackedArrayQ :> arr,a->1, b->2}``). The added rule is instructing to be idle on packed arrays, which would prevent them from unpacking.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, that's a nice trick! Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: No problem ) Was glad to help.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: +1, nice tip on the ruleset modification.

Comment: @rasher Thanks. This indeed comes handy at times.

Comment: @Öskå Ok, done now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's happening is that `ReplaceAll` unpacks packed arrays during rule application, as a part of the pattern-matching procedure. This happens because for general patterns, there is no automatic way to exclude packed arrays in advance (to know that they or their elements won't match a given pattern).

The way to handle this situation is to use the fact that only the first matching rule applies for any given expression. Therefore, all you have to do is to add an idle rule like the following:

```
arr_List?Developer`PackedArrayQ :> arr
```

in front of your rules. So, if your rules look like

```
{a->1, b->2}
```

then the new rule set will look like

```
{arr_List?Developer`PackedArrayQ :> arr,a->1, b->2}
```

This will ensure that any packed array encountered by the pattern-matcher in `ReplaceAll` will be left untouched (and, in particular, unpacked). Note that this only works for `ReplaceAll`, because it is breadth-first, and goes from expressions to sub-expressions.

Most replacement functions are depth-first (the similar situation with `Cases`  [was considered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700934/why-is-cases-so-slow-here-are-there-any-tricks-to-speed-it-up)), and there isn't such a simple solution in that case (because for depth-first traversal, unpacking happens as a part of the traversal, rather than part of the pattern-matching. There, lists are unpacked even before the pattern-matcher has a chance to "see" them as a whole).