# How do I replace part of a matrix?

Tags: matrix, replacement

Imagine we have:

```
a = RandomInteger[1, {50, 150, 53}];
b = RandomInteger[1, {50, 150, 53}];
mask = RandomInteger[1, {50, 150, 53}];
```

How do I replace a(mask) with b(mask)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this when `a` and `b` may contain *any* kind of symbolic expression could be

```
With[{pos = Position[mask, 1]},
  ReplacePart[a, Thread[pos -> Extract[b, pos]]]
]
```

Here, first you get the positions at which `mask` contains `1`. Then, you replace every part of `a` at these positions with the corresponding entry of `b` at this position.

Assuming `a`, `b`, and `mask` only contain 0 or 1 you can use the much faster solution:

```
a - BitAnd[a, mask] + BitAnd[b, mask]
```

or, even faster:

```
BitOr[BitAnd[a, BitNot[mask]], BitAnd[b, mask]]
```

Here are the timings in comparison:

```
a - BitAnd[a, mask] + BitAnd[b, mask] // RepeatedTiming // First
(* 0.012 *)

BitOr[BitAnd[a, BitNot[mask]], BitAnd[b, mask]] // RepeatedTiming // First
(* 0.0075 *)
```

the latter being even faster than @Shadowray's solution:

```
(b - a)*mask + a // RepeatedTiming // First
(* 0.0098 *)
```

Answer (score 8):

If `mask` may contain only zeros and ones, then you can do such assignment arithmetically:

```
(b - a)*mask + a
```

Since arithmetic operations on arrays are highly optimized, this solution should be quite fast:

```
(b - a)*mask + a; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.000885

Comment: I think this gives a wrong result. Try, e.g., `a = ConstantArray[
  1, {2, 3}]; b = {{1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}; mask = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 
   1}};`

Comment: @JEM_Mosig I have corrected the answer (exchanged `a` and `b`)